# Print logstash event in ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash

Hello I'm exporting logs from RabbitMQ. In order to debug, I would like to print the content of the message before applying some regex and base64 decode. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
        host => "***host***"
        vhost => "/"
        exchange => "Exchange"
        key => "#"
  }
}

filter {
  ruby {
        code => "print event['message']"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
  }
}
```

But I only have `nil` values for my messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to print the message.

```
input {
    stdin{}
}

filter {
    ruby {
            code => "
                    puts event['message']
            "
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

FYI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the only thing printed is lines feed (CRLF) ... Maybe there is something to do with encoding?

Comment: I have update the answer. This is the config i use. It can print out all the message in the event['message']. I think in your case maybe it is not the problem of ruby filter .

Comment: Using your .conf works but the filter has no effect, it will print the same result to stdout with our without the filter.
This code:

filter {
    ruby {
            code => "
                    puts event
            "
    }
}

returns:

2014-08-18T09:52:34.162+0000 %{host} %{message}

but yours only returns CRLF when output is different from stdout ...

Answer (score 1):

filter {

ruby {
code =>'hash=Hash[event]
puts hash
'
}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).